# How can i block my website from loading resources from another domain?

Tags: html, wordpress, .htaccess, cpanel

I need to find a quick fix to block my website from accessing resource that is being loaded from another domain, similar to hosts file in Windows. How can I do this?

I haven't tried anything because I can't find anything.

Comment: Why? What is the usecase. You can scan your server files for http and https

Comment: From where/how are these resources accessed? You can try to disable [`allow_furl_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) in php to disable opening files from another url.

Comment: You cannot prevent any DNS injection because when your codes loaded on client it will route from that client But to makes it more secure you always must use SSL on requests in that way it become more difficult to rewrite but still not fixed your problem 100 percent.

Comment: I don`t have full control of website code until Monday and I need to block a specific image from loading on a Wordpress store.

Comment: The "hosts" file has nothing to do with blocking content. In contrary: it allows to _find_ content, to resolve names to addresses.

Comment: You should take the site down if that really is that important.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could tell the browser where it is _allowed_ to load external content from, via [Content Security Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP) - but that you can not use that to specifically "block" anything, only to allow stuff. So you would need to be really careful not to break any functionality, when you try to implement this in a hurry ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use cloud flare to block this, this allows to access the content from the domain allows by you and rest will be blocked

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).